# Let $x,y,a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$. If $x+y\equiv 0\ (\mathrm{mod}\ 3)$ and $a\equiv b\ (\mathrm{mod}\ 3)$, then show that $ax+by\equiv 0\ (\mathrm{mod}\ 3)$.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, divisibility, integers

Stuck on this homework problem. At this point I know the basic definitions of what it means to be congruent, I just can't seem to link them together to solve this problem, and I'm not really sure how to use the $x+y\equiv 0\ (\mathrm{mod}\ 3)$

I assume I must expand/alter something and then plug it into the $ax+by\equiv 0\ (\mathrm{mod}\ 3)$.

So far for this proof, I know to $a\equiv b\ (\mathrm{mod}\ 3)$, which then implies that $a = b + 3k$, for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Similarly, $b= a + 3j$ for some $j\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Any help on how to link these theorems would be appreciated.

Comment: Please use mathjax. [Here's a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: $a\equiv  b\pmod3\implies ax+by\equiv ax+ay=a(x+y)\pmod3$

Comment: @jeea: r does not need to be 0 modulo 3, it can be any number

Comment: See my (updated) comment on John's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can substitute $b=a+3k$ for some $k$ since $a\equiv b\text{ mod }3$

Then $ax+by=ax+(a+3k)y=ax+ay+3yk=a(x+y)+3yk$.

Since $x+y$ is a multiple of $3$, both terms of the sum are divisible by $3$ so $$ax+by\equiv 0\text{ mod }3$$

Comment: This works, but you shouldn't "unwind" the definition of a congruence like that. Rather, the point of congruences is that they enjoy the same sort of (ring) *equational* 
 logic that we know well from grade school, so we can effortlessly *reuse* these equational skills, e.g. as below

Comment: $\qquad\qquad\qquad\begin{align}\color{#c00}a\ \ \,&\equiv\, \color{#c00}b\\ -x\,&\equiv\,\ \ y\\\[.5em] \hline 
\Rightarrow\,\ {-}\color{#c00}ax\,&\equiv \,\color{#c00}by\end{align}\ \ \ $ by the [Congruence Product Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)